# A question about modifying values of one array based on values in another array

Tags: python-3.x, numpy-ndarray

Consider a 2D numpy array, a 1D numpy array, and a constant:

```
arr1 = [[ 4  4]       arr2 = [ 1  7]        k = 2
        [ 3  6]
        [ 7 10] 
        [-2  6]
        [-1  6]
        [-8  8]]
```

Here's what I need to do:  If the absolute value of the values in arr1[:,0] are in arr2, then I need to subtract k from the corresponding values in arr1[:,1].     The final output should be:

```
arr1 = [[ 4  4]      
        [ 3  6]
        [ 7  8] 
        [-2  6]
        [-1  4]
        [-8  8]]
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Still learning, but this seems to work:

```
print(arr1[np.in1d(abs[:,0]), arr2), 1] -= k)
```